# exporting data from table to .csv file

Tags: mysql, csv, select-into-outfile

I'm trying to load data of a table into a csv file. However rows in file are broken in between. The data of table seems fine and there is no \n anywhere. Then why am I getting breaks in rows?
Query I'm executing is

```
select * from `abc_csv` into outfile '/home/abc.csv'  
 fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n';
```

And the result I'm getting is:

```
A,B,C,D,  
,E,F
```

While all these entries belong to the same record

Comment: How your data in your table Looks like?

Comment: if it's a file created in windows you may need terminated by '\r\n'

Comment: data in my table is:

A B C D E F 
i.e. each letter is in different column

Comment: @kavya.jain why can't you post the database design . If you post it it will be very useful for coding your output.